# Title window in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I want to make title window (pop up) in flex .. which contains some buttons if i click on any button then another button has to add outside the title window
can anyone help me out.
Thanking you

Answer (score 2):

Pop ups can be achieved using the `Alert` class. Say for showing a pop up below code might work

```
Alert.show("Alert Text", "Title", Alert.OK, this, start_app);
```

The `Alert.OK` specifies the buttons to be included. You can include more by using `OR` operator. The labels of these button can also be changed to meet your requirements. The `start_app` is called the `closeHandler` which will be triggered if any button in the `Alert` is pressed. Further logic can be put in the `closeHanlder`. For detailed information see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html

Comment: thanks for your ans.. but i want new window to open in button click ..(which is inside in popup window.)